# TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'finally'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I am using angular 1.6 with gulp and es6 promise which has `.finally()` block, its working fine all other except IE Edge and IE 11.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: use angularjs promises with [`$q` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: ES6 does not support `finally`, but ES2018 will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be supported by either of them (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally)

Comment: Is there any other way to do functionality like finally block will execute at either of the case success or reject?

Comment: Hey, i guess you could use Promise.all or combine then and catch as an alternative : `promise.then(() => doSomething()).catch(() => doSomethingElse()).then(() => onFinish())`

Answer (score 1):

Some more information:

- ChakraCore - Implement Promise.prototype.finally Fixes #3520

  - https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/pull/4668
  - (as 27/09/2018) So in Chakra, but not in Edge yet.

In Edge devtools for **Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134**:

```
typeof (new Promise(()=>1).finally)
"undefined"

typeof (new Promise(()=>1).then)
"function"

typeof (new Promise(()=>1).catch)
"function"
```

---

For my application I was using https://cdnjs.com/libraries/es6-promise to polyfill `Promise` (initially this was solely to polyfill for IE 11).

But then I noticed my app wasn't working in Edge.

Related issue - https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise/issues/330#issuecomment-425233364

Now I have switched to Bluebird to polyfill for both IE 11 and Edge.